# getCurrentActivityName() under the class Uidevice says as depricated. What is the equivalent of it. In code i want to fetch the current activity name

Tags: android, automation

I am using object of `UiDevice` class and currently using the method
 `getCurrentActivityName()` to get the activity name. Thids method is deprected and giving irrelevant output. What is the equivalent of it.

Comment: Please share with us your code example with error.

Comment: There is no error . This function is said to be deprecated and no more reliable. But could'nt find any equivalent of this method. for example for the below adb command output is,    
  adb shell "dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'"
  mCurrentFocus=Window{ca8194f u0 xxx/yyy}
  mFocusedApp=AppWindowToken{aba6526 token=Token{f517081 ActivityRecord{5187468 u0 xxx/yyy t76}}}

I want to get the activity name "yyy" from code.
This method "getCurrentActivityName()" is deprecated from UiDEvice Class. Can i get the equivalent of it ??